# Удалён вопрос, так как "посвящён стремительно меняющейся ситуации"

Tags: обсуждение, удаление-вопросов, удаление-ответов

Заметил [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471171/%D0%90-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-whatsapp-%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B7/742638#742638) вопрос. Был удалён с причиной "Вопрос посвящён стремительно меняющейся ситуации". Ведь с такой причиной можно много какие вопросы закрыть. У того же FB/Google api периодически меняется.

Почему бы информацию о том, что "API закрылся/поменялся" не оформить в виде ответа вместо удаления всего вопроса?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это я удалил вопрос. Дело было так.

На вопрос был дан новый ответ, в котором по существу была только ссылка на фейсбук. На фейсбуке — отзыв на сервис для рассылки сообщений. У автора в профиле есть личный сайт, на сайте в списке проектов — этот сервис. (Это к тому, что я не раскрываю данных, полученных через инструменты модератора).

В ответе нет даже примера кода для интеграции с сервисом — значит его стоит удалить или преобразовать в комментарий.
Автор связан с продуктом, так что ответ можно даже отметить как спам, но я не стал. Не использую эту тревогу, когда живые люди неосторожно что-то рекламируют. Тревога «спам» вызывает жесткие последствия, заточенные на блокировку настоящих бездушных спамеров.

Потом я посмотрел на второй ответ, рекомендующий неофициальный API.
Репозиторий этого API на гитхабе уже несколько лет как «зачищен» — автор пишет, что его замучали юристы.
Ответ потерял смысл — значит и его нужно удалить.

Почему оба ответа неудачные? Потому что вопрос неудачный. Сначала я отметил его плашкой про меняющуюся ситуацию, потом ещё немного подумал — и просто удалил. Вряд ли от него будет польза, пока WhatsApp не откроет API.

Так что плашка и удаление связаны только косвенно. Не существует причины удаления «Вопрос посвящён стремительно меняющейся ситуации».

Если бы вопрос был получше, ответу хватило бы примера кода и упоминания о том, что автор причастен к сервису. Был бы хороший ответ.